# Sum of two counts from different table with different conditions

Tags: mysql

Basically I need to merge these into one single query:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT id ) AS totalRows1 
FROM other_events WHERE status = "approved" 
AND Location = 1

SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT Id ) AS totalRows2 
FROM core_events WHERE Status = "Active"
AND Location_id = 1
```

When I do it like below, if there is no event with Location_id = 1 query returns 0. In that condition I need it to return the count of the first table only.

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT t1.id ) + COUNT( DISTINCT t2.Id ) AS total
FROM other_events AS t1, core_events AS t2
WHERE t1.status = "approved"
AND t1.Location = 1
AND t2.Location_id = 1
AND t2.Status = 'Active'
```

ps. column names are exactly like above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `UNION` statement to merge the result like this:

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS total
    FROM other_events
    WHERE (status = "approved" AND Location = 1)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Id) AS total
    FROM core_events
    WHERE (Location_id = 1 AND Status = 'Active')
) union_result
```

Comment: I tried this but, when I tested with t2.Location_id = 4 (which is only one row) then it gives me a really big number instead of adding 1 more to the count. If it exists, then it should be summing up and if not just the first one should be counted. I really don't know why this above would give me almost 4 times of the first count.

Comment: Updated, have a try. @Ekin

Comment: Yes, works like a charm! Thanks a lot @luoluo :) Learned another thing thanks to you.